# Is it possible to use an outgoing SMTP server from Laos?

Tags: internet, smtp

While traveling in Lao PDR, I've subscribed to an unlimited cellular data plan (at [Lao Telecom](http://www.laotel.com)) because I have to maintain some websites during my trip. Everything works fine (connection is even pretty fast) but I would like to be able to use an *outgoing SMTP server* for some reasons related to a bug I encounter in one of these websites.

I can obtain SSH access and was used to connect to the french Free ISP smtp.free.fr outgoing SMTP server habitually, but this one requires to be under a Free connection.

Comment: I think it is off-topic here. But why are you asking? Did you test whether it works?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SamTap

Comment: @Bernhard for sure I test it before I ask

Comment: Another auto correct fail... I meant SMTP

Comment: Can you access other ports? In which case I can suggest a SSH tunnel

Comment: Also simple SSH is a good thing to try.

Comment: @andra SSH is available

Comment: I think this is a good question but it's not a travel question. I'm not sure if it belongs on SuperUser, ServerFault, or StackOverflow. I would tend toward SuperUser because I use it for questions vaguely similar.

Comment: Do you need to be able to use an outgoing SMTP server that is physically inside the country of Laos, or has a *.la DNS/rDNS, or has a Lao Telecom IP, or do you just need to be able to access ANY outgoing SMTP server from your connection?

Comment: @K.A : I need to be able to access any outgoing SMTP server from my connection. For example, in France, I use smtp.free.fr, that can be accessed only when you are connected to the Free ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prerequisites - if the following is true:

1. you want the computer with which you are connecting to be able to connect a specific port on a destination host: farhost:farport
2. the farhost:farport is unreachable - you did check with a simple tcp connect (using telnet or other means trying to establish a connection)
3. you can configure the software that wants to connect to farhost:farport to connect to localhost:localport
4. you can establish a SSH connection to a "known good" host on the internet (goodhost), that can connect to farhost:farport

then a possible solution is to run SSH on your local computer, forwarding a port on localhost over the SSH connection via the "known good" host to the far host, for example

```
ssh -L localport:farhost:farport goodhost
```

and to configure the application to connect to localhost:localport

Comment: It seems to be very simple now you've explained how to deal with it. Thanx

Comment: :-) but wait, there's more - check out SSH option `-D` to fake a SOCKS firewall, tunneling most of your network traffice over the SSH connection